# Stuck on: 'There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is underdetermined'

Tags: differential-equations

First time here, I'm a newbie to Mathematica (so this is probably a pretty basic question). I've spent hours trying to solve an equation, I set this up as a practice but it doesn't work, giving me the message "There are more dependent variables, {f[t],g[t],h[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined"

```
NDSolve[
  {3 f[x] + 2 g'[x] + 3 h'[x] == 0,
   3 f'[x] + g[x] + 3 h[x] == 0,
   f[x] - h'[x] == 2,
   f[0] == 1,
   g[0] == 0,
   h[0] == -2,
   f'[0] == 1,
   g'[0] == -1,
   h'[0] == 1,
   f''[0] == 0.1,
   f'''[0] == 12,
   f''''[0] == 11},
  {f[t], g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 4}, 
  Method -> {"Automatic", {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}}];
```

No matter how many intial conditions (-and equations-) I've tried to add (carefree) it does not output anything. For the moment, any form of solution whatsoever would be fine.

When I did a search on the site, the examples were either too complicated or were about 'over-determined'.

Thanks

Comment: Replace all the `t`s by `x`s (or vice versa).  And get rid of the extraneous ICs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh wow I'm a fool. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, but the error message sent you looking the wrong way.  (Though for that message, they're counting differential equations, not initial conditions, but that's not very clear at all. Try it without the `Method` and not enough ICs, and you'll see a different error message.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 maybe it would be more useful to me to post the code I'm actually having problem with. I'll ask another question in that case. Also, thank you again! It is no longer giving me that message.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm drafting something and it says the body paragraph is too long. I just checked meta but I couldn't find anything. What should I do?

Comment: Why your need `f''[0] == 0.1,f'''[0] == 12, f''''[0] == 11` ? This is only a first order ODE system.

Comment: With your initial conditions for `f,g,h` and their 1st derivatives, the first three equations are not true at `x==0`. The system has no solution as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly because I dislike finding questions with all the answers in the comments, I'll give an answer with my method of code writing, which will help in general readability and solution to the problem.

First create an array of your odes:

```
odes = {3 f[x] + 2 g'[x] + 3 h'[x] == 0, 3 f'[x] + g[x] + 3 h[x] == 0,f[x] - h'[x] == 2}
```

Then your initial conditions:

```
ics = {f[0] == 1, g[0] == 0, h[0] == -2, f'[0] == 1, g'[0] == -1, h'[0] == 1}
```

Now your `NDSolve[]` with corrected dependant variable `x` instead of `t`

```
NDSolve[{odes, ics}, {f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, Method -> {"Automatic", {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}}]
```

This will provide a solution to the problem, but create other errors that may or may not be acceptable.